# How to move out of quill editor using tab

Tags: angularjs, quill

I am using AngularJS. Currently when I press tab in quill editor it adds a tab character. Is there a way I can configure the editor so when I press tab or any special key I move out to next component.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is directly using the modules prop, as shown [here](https://codepen.io/toddlr/pen/rmNdpR)

```js
modules = {
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
        tab: {
          key: 9,
          handler: function (range, context) {
            return true;
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I add this and use TAB key to exit editor the "selection-change" event is no longer fired, so if you are listening to that for getting the content and set the value of a textfield to be posted back to server, you need to expicitly call your own blur function in this.

Answer (score 1):

```
quill.keyboard.addBinding({ key: 'tab' }, function(range) {
    // Call focus event and specify input which you want highlight
    // return true;
});
```

Comment: // @ts-ignore
this.editor.keyboard.bindings[9] = [];

If you get an error or isn't work in Angular14 you can try this code.